# How to interactively remove properties drawer under point

Tags: org-mode

Currently when I need to remove a property drawer under an entry:

- I have move to either the beginning (`:PROPERTIES`) or the end (`:END:`)
- Then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to fold (hide) the drawer.
- And finally delete the line, which has the effect of deleting the whole folded drawer.

These 3 steps operation can be cumbersome sometimes and I'd like to be able to remove a whole properties drawer in one key binding, with the point starting anywhere inside.

Looking at the doc and provided functions in Org-mode, I can't find such a function. I searched for a combination of terms like `org delete`, `org remove`, `org drawer`… without success.

I did found related functions like : `org-insert-drawer` or `org-remove-empty-drawer-at`, but not the one I need.

Am I missing something obvious? Which pieces are needed to design my own? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [org-element-api](https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-element-api.html) to create a custom interactive function (command) for this, e.g.:

```lisp
(defun my-kill-drawer ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((element (org-element-context)))
    (unless (eq (car element) 'drawer)
      (setq element (org-element-property :parent element)))
    (kill-region (org-element-property :begin element)
                 (org-element-property :end element))))
```

Comment: @NickD Thanks, you are right, it's a remnant of the 'design process'. I have removed it from the answer...